# Error in netbean during compiling

Tags: c++, c, gcc, netbeans, mingw

i have installed msys and also add path to bin in system but still got some errors.

```
"/C/msys/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/d/NetBeansProjekty/CppApplication_2'
"/C/msys/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/d/NetBeansProjekty/CppApplication_2'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d
g++ -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
make.exe[2]: g++: Command not found
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 127
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/d/NetBeansProjekty/CppApplication_2'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/d/NetBeansProjekty/CppApplication_2'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 852ms)
```

Can you tell me wheres problem?

now I added mingw path but also popped new derror

```
   "/C/msys/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=
   SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf make.exe[1]: Entering directory
   `/d/NetBeansProjekty/CppApplication_2' "/C/msys/bin/make.exe" -f
   nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk
   dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe make.exe[2]: Entering
   directory `/d/NetBeansProjekty/CppApplication_2' mkdir -p
   dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows g++ -o
   dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_2
   build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newmain.o
   build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newmain.o: In function `main':
   D:\NetBeansProjekty\CppApplication_2/newmain.cpp:5: multiple
   definition of `main'
   build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:D:\NetBeansProjekty\CppApplication_2/main.cpp:15:
   first defined here collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe]
   Error 1 make.exe[2]: Leaving directory
   `/d/NetBeansProjekty/CppApplication_2' make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf]
   Error 2 make.exe[1]: Leaving directory
   `/d/NetBeansProjekty/CppApplication_2' make.exe": *** [.build-impl]
   Error 2
```

---

Comment: Look carefully, you will see "g++: Command not found". That's the problem. g++ needs to be in your path.

Comment: Finally, rewrote paths restarted program and its working, thanks!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and and *accept* it, so others see it's solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the paths and restarted the program and its working.